# Cannot GET / expo react

Tags: reactjs, express, expo, stripe-payments

[image]
I'm trying to connect to stripe server using express framework but I keep getting this error in the image I attached above.

```
import express from "express";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "pk_test......";
const SECRET_KEY = "sk_test.........";


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not did a `GET` method. Try to do - above the listening:

```
app.get('/',(req, res)=>{
    res.send('Hello World')
});
```

Now, when you call *http://localhost:3000/* you will see **Hello World**.

Comment: Hi the code works but I'm still getting the cannot read properties of undefined is that normal ?

Comment: Are you running just this code? I reproduced the same code here, and didn't received the error...This type of error normally occurs when you try to read a variable that has a undefined value, but in this case that is not even a variable 'locale

Comment: The issue was with an extension I added